# Change icon with click on button. Java

Tags: java, button, icons

I use Netbeans to make a Java application. I am still a beginner. I have 4 buttons and I want to change an icon, when a user click one of them. I have already put buttons and one icon but I have no idea on how to continue.

Comment: What more you know about JButton ? Do you know how to add ActionListener to them ? Show us some effort first

Comment: I add only the JButtons and an Icon. At this moment, i don't know about ActionListener but i'll try and search about it. But i am really confused now. I'm sorry because i don't show you some effort but i am at the begin of my try.

Comment: Finally,I dit it.. Thanks for "ActionListener" !!! :) Now,i have another problem.. How can i undestand which button has clicked by the user? Everyone who knows?

Answer (score 1):

You will need an `ActionListener` that changes the icon (use an ImageIcon for this). Add that ActionListener to the Button which should be responding to a click, with that action.

```
button.addActionListener(/*here your listener*/);
```

Comment: We all know that. But we can at least expect him to know about one listeners which might show us his effort.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i am begginer,so if you can give me more details or an example,it will be so helpfull.

Comment: @Sage: I know. I just told him what to look for. I didn't throw the complete code answer in here. When the OP shows not much effort, I will keep my answer simple and guide into the right direction, by providing the terms to search for.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux, Thanks for that. But I think it might be more reasonable to give hints in comments. Please don't get me wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the windowbuilder of netbeans?
If yes, check the generated code for your specified button and see how they did it :)

Comment: I don't understand exacty what i have to do.. :(

Comment: If you can wait till tomorrow, i gonna post you an example!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i created a new JFrame Form to my package called TestFrame.

```
public class TestFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        static public ImageIcon imageCross; 
        static public ImageIcon imageCircle;


        URL cross = TestFrame.class.getResource("cross.jpg");
        URL circle = TestFrame.class.getResource("circle.jpg");

        boolean clicked = true;
    /**
     * Creates new form TestFrame
     */
    public TestFrame() {
        imageCross = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(cross);
        imageCircle = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(circle);
        initComponents();
    }
    ...
```

This is just how i declare my images.

Now i need to change them when i click on a button.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if(clicked) {
        jButton1.setIcon(imageCircle);
        clicked = false;
    } else {
        jButton1.setIcon(imageCross);
        clicked = true;
    }

}
```

Just add all your images you need. Add for every single JButton a actionPerformed() and switch your icons with a if-condition or maybe switch/case ( if you have more).